# What does the semicolon actually do?

Tags: java

I was looking at a typical for loop:

```
class ForDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args){
         for(int i=1; i<11; i++){
              System.out.println("Count is: " + i);
         }
    }
}
```

I am happy with the semicolons after `int i=1`: it is a **statement** which declares the new variable `i`. If `i++` is also a **statement**, why doesn't it have a semicolon after?

Another example. I opened the Jshell and put the following:

```
jshell> int a=1;
a ==> 1
jshell> a++
$2 ==> 1
jshell> a
a ==> 2
jshell> int b=1;
b ==> 1
jshell> b++;
$5 ==> 1
jshell> b
b ==> 2
```

In other words the command `++` works, independently from whether there is a semicolon or not. I expected not to work without it.

Last example (adapted from a presentation about the difference between `=` and `==`):

```
jshell> boolean x = false;
x ==> false
jshell> if (x = true) System.out.println("Sorry! This is wrong ...");
Sorry! This is wrong ...
jshell> boolean x = false;
x ==> false
jshell> if (x = true;) System.out.println("Sorry! This is wrong ...");
|  Error:
|  ')' expected
|  if (x = true;) System.out.println("Sorry! This is wrong ...");
|              ^
```

I get the point about the difference between = and ==. My question is why it works in the first half (`if (x = true)` without `;`), and not with a `;` (`if (x = true;)`).

Apologies for the several examples, but I think the question is relatively straightforward: if there are instances where an expression (without `;`) works as a command statement (with `;`), what is the function of semicolons?

Comment: " If i++ is also a statement, why doesn't it have a semicolon after?" - i++ is an expression which *can* be a statement, but in the for loop declaration, it *isn't* a statement. I would strongly advise you to ignore the jshell aspect - basically jshell can have its own rules; focus on the Java language rules.

Comment: The semi-colon does nothing. It's only used to separate expressions and statements. It's just part of the language's syntax. JShell interprets code slightly differently than the Java compiler, it doesn't always require a semi-colon.

Comment: The semicolon has no semantic meaning, it's just used at the end of statements in Java. It's like a full stop in English - we write it at the end of a sentence, the sentence would have the same meaning without it, the sentence is just syntactically wrong without it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The semiccolon is a separator of stack calls. The inside of `if()` wants a **boolean**, not a stack call.
Only inside the `{}` are statements expected.

The inside of `for()` expects three stack calls: One defining the loop variable, one defining the breaking clause and one defining what happens after each loop.

Example:
The construct `for(;;);` is a valid java construct. But you should never use it as the only thing it would do is loop over nothing forever: You don't define a variable, a breaking condition or something that gets executed after each call. During the loop you also just do nothing.

Comment: I understand why for(;;); is valid. My question is another: why doesn't one write for(;;;) (i.e. with an extra semicolon)

Comment: Because the ";" is a SEPARATOR of statements. If you wrote for(;;;), you would actually define four empty statements, which is not what the for-loop expects (3 statements). (Sorry if this too late, I don't check my inbox often.)

Answer (score 3):

The semicolon *does* nothing, it is there because a `for` loop is (amongst others) defined as

> BasicForStatement:
> for ( ForInitopt ; Expressionopt ; ForUpdateopt ) Statement

according to https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html

There are by definition two semicolons between the three parts.